# Error message when globally installing brunch

Tags: node.js, brunch

Every time I try to install brunch by inputting "npm install -g brunch" in the command line, I get the following error message:

```
> fsevents@0.3.0 install /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/brunch/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o


In file included from ../fsevents.cc:86:
../src/constants.cc:10:66: warning: template argument uses unnamed type [-Wunnamed-type-template-args]
  object->Set(NanNew<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone"), NanNew<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEvent...

                                                                 ^~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:290:1: note: 
      unnamed type used in template argument was declared here
enum {
^


1 warning generated.

      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node: Finished
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/brunch -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch
brunch@1.7.17 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/brunch


├── debug@0.7.4
├── async-waterfall@0.1.5
├── async-each@0.1.4
├── commonjs-require-definition@0.1.2
├── commander@2.0.0
├── ncp@0.4.2
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── init-skeleton@0.2.4 (rimraf@2.2.8)
├── loggy@0.2.0 (growl@1.7.0, ansi-color@0.2.1, date-utils@1.2.16)
├── source-map@0.1.40 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── coffee-script@1.8.0
├── anysort@0.2.0 (anymatch@0.2.0)
├── read-components@0.6.1 (component-builder@0.10.1)
├── pushserve@0.1.6 (connect-slashes@0.0.11, express@3.3.8)
└── chokidar@0.9.0 (recursive-readdir@0.0.2, fsevents@0.3.0)
```

Comment: It's only a warning, not an error.

Comment: I can't find the source (it's somewhere on SO) but you may be able to solve it by changing npm permissions

Comment: How do I change npm permissions?

Comment: @Scimonster, yes, it's a warning not an error but it won't allow me to move on and install brunch.

Comment: @elenawalom Brunch *is* installed. You can ignore the warning.

Comment: Just FYI, it comes from the fsevents sub-dependency, and started occurring with an update to XCode. See https://github.com/pipobscure/fsevents/issues/33

Answer (score 1):

I also have this printed when I do `npm install -g brunch` but it does get installed for me.

It also appears that it gets installed for you, because NPM prints dependency tree only when something is installed successfully.

Running `brunch` should give you

```
  Usage: brunch [command] [options]

  Commands:

    new [skeleton] [path]  Create new brunch project in path [.]. Short-cut: n
    build [options]        Build a brunch project. Short-cut: b
    watch [options]        Watch brunch directory and rebuild if something changed. Short-cut: w

  Options:

    -h, --help     output usage information
    -V, --version  output the version number
```

now.

If it doesn't, either one is true:

- Your shell doesn't know about the path to installed `brunch` binary;
- I'm wrong and it didn't get installed for some reason.

In my case, `brunch` binary got installed as `/usr/local/bin/brunch`. It might be different for you because I'm using [N](https://github.com/visionmedia/n). I strongly suggest you use it too to avoid any problems with permissions and to be able to switch Node versions.

You might want to try to set N up and try again with N—maybe the problem will go away and that'll be it.